# How to search and retrieve data from json file in Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a json file with below data.

```
{"student1":[{"id":1,"name":"Test Data1","email":"test1@g.com"}]}

{"student2":[{"id":2,"name":"Test Data2","email":"test2@g.com"}]}

{"student3":[{"id":3,"name":"Test Data3","email":"test3@g.com"}]}

{"student4":[{"id":4,"name":"Test Data4","email":"test4@g.com"}]}
```

And I use $.getJSON method to retrieve but data won't output. And I want to search data with Key like student3, then the data of student3 will have to output.
Here is my JQuery code.

```
$.getJSON( "test.json", function( data ) {
          var items = [];
          $.each( data, function( key, val ) {
            items.push( "<li id='" + key + "'>" + val + "</li>" );
          });

          $( "<ul/>", {
            "class": "my-new-list",
            html: items.join( "" )
          }).appendTo( "body" );
    });
```

Here is my Full Source Code.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
   <head>
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <title>Test Json</title>
  </head>
  <body>
     <input type="text" name="name" id="name">
     <input type="text" name="email" id="email">
     <input type="button" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" onclick="submitForm()">
     <input type="button" name="edit" id="edit" value="Edit" onclick="Edit()">
     <br><br>
     <div></div>
 </body>

 <script type="text/javascript">
    function submitForm(){
    var name = $("#name").val();
    var email = $("#email").val();
    var obj = {
       table: []
    };
    obj.table.push({id: 1, name:name, email:email});
    var json = JSON.stringify(obj);
    $.ajax
    ({
        type: "GET",
        dataType : 'json',
        url: 'save_json.php',
        data: { data: json },
        success: function () {alert("Thanks!"); },
        failure: function() {alert("Error!");}
    });
    $("#name").val('');
    $("#email").val('');
}


  function Edit(){
    $.getJSON( "general.json", function( data ) {

          var items = [];
          $.each( data, function( key, val ) {
            items.push( "<li id='" + key + "'>" + val + "</li>" );
          });

          $( "<ul/>", {
            "class": "my-new-list",
            html: items.join( "" )
          }).appendTo( "body" );
    });
   }
 </script>
 </html>
```

Comment: What you have in that file is not JSON, it's 4 different objects. Because of the format it's in, you cannot retrieve it. You need to either convert it to a single object and use `$.getScript()`, or change it to JSON and use your current logic.

Comment: Can you show me with sample? I'm noob. Please...

Answer (score 0):

Please add below mentioned code.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $.getJSON( "test.json", function(data) {
          var items = [];       

     $.each( data, function( key, val ) {
        $.each( val, function( key2, val2 ) {
          items.push( "<li id='" + key2 + "'>" +val2[0].name + "</li>" );
        });  
      });

          $( "<ul/>", {
            "class": "my-new-list",
            html: items.join( "" )
          }).appendTo( "body" );
    });
});
```

> also remove student1,student2 and use only student and find value
>   using key.

Your json data will be something like below.

```
[{"student":[{"id":1,"name":"Shyam","email":"test@g.com"}]},
{"student":[{"id":1,"name":"Niraj","email":"test@g.com"}]},
{"student":[{"id":1,"name":"Mehul","email":"test@g.com"}]},
{"student":[{"id":1,"name":"Ritesh","email":"test@g.com"}]}]
```

Let me know if it not works.

Comment: it's work bro. Thanks . But my json data add format not like that bro. i'll show you with code.

Comment: I was updated my Question above bro. Please guide me and help me.

Comment: Json format is the main issue i think, see i have update my code. take updated  **$each**  loops and add in your Edit() function.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code/syntax may not be correct....

searchParam  would be 'Student3'..

```
 $.getJSON( "test.json", function( data , searchParam ) {
              var items = [];
var filterObj =data[searchParam];
if(filterObj != undefined)
{
               var parsedData = Json.Parse(filterObj);
              $.each( parsedData , function( key, val ) {                
                items.push( "<li id='" + key + "'>" + val + "</li>" );
              });

              $( "<ul/>", {
                "class": "my-new-list",
                html: items.join( "" )
              }).appendTo( "body" );
        });
}
```